# Lock Tables - PHPMyAdmin not working

Tags: phpmyadmin, locking

I am trying to lock a table name 'users' but unable to lock using PHPMyAdmin.
I followed this [tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-table-locking/)
but the following error occurs:

[image: error while locking a table]

> Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 0)

Comment: This appears to be an issue with the SQL parser used by phpMyAdmin, which I've reported as a bug at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/issues/180

Comment: So have you received any response? Have you any alternative option for this?

Answer (score 3):

It's not useful to use the LOCK TABLES statement in phpMyAdmin unless you type some other statements after it and send them altogether with the LOCK TABLES statement. The reason is that the lock applies only to the current MySQL session, which will be discarded as soon as phpMyAdmin finishes processing the statement. We're not talking about PHP sessions but MySQL sessions.

Answer (score 2):

The first part of the problem is that phpMyAdmin currently seems to have a problem recognizing the syntax, so you get the red X syntax warning. However, you can still submit the query around that, it's just a warning. As I mentioned in a comment, I just opened a bug report about this so it should get fixed for an upcoming release.

However, the second part is the error MySQL gives you back, which is shown at the bottom of the screen, and it's saying that your syntax is also not valid for MySQL. You haven't told it what type of lock you want; you could do something like `` LOCK TABLES `users` READ `` and it should work for you (despite the phpMyAdmin warning). Your choices are essentially READ or WRITE, with READ also allowing the LOCAL modifier ([MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html)). When I tested both the current stable (4.7.5) and development versions of phpMyAdmin, they both worked correctly with this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me once  when I attempted to import SQL backup files created using MySQL Workbench into PHPMyAdmin. But when the LOCK and UNLOCK lines are commented it works fine.Else install Workbench and restore without any changes.